# Dynamic Abbreviations in PyCharm?

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, pycharm

Is there any sort of plugin or setting in PyCharm to enable dynamic abbreviations as per the [dabbrev](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html) functionality in Emacs?

When running Python's interactive console, I would like a shortcut key that auto-completes from the list of words inside my open buffers and interactive consoles, rather than from a list of functions in the project.

For example:

> print "Ency" + "clo" + "pedia"
>
> Encyclopedia

(in emacs:) En ALT+/  ===> autocompletes to Enclyclopedia.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that ALT + / also works in PyCharm.